# Use the Image class of Prestashop in another directory

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm facing something that seems to be easy but I'm just stuck!

I'm trying to use the `Image` class of Prestashop (in my script) to handle resizing of images. (to be used after).

So,

**My script is located under:**

`EDI/modules/Article`

**Picture class is under  `classes`**

So if I want to use the Picture class from my script I do this :

```
include_once (ROOT_PATH . '/config/config.inc.php');
include_once (ROOT_PATH . '/classes/Image.php');
```

And that's where I'm stuck, php says :

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB::getInstance() in ..../config/alias.php on line 65**

This came from

```
function pSQL($string, $htmlOK = false)
{
    // Avoid thousands of "Db::getInstance()"...
    static $db = false;
    
    if (!$db)
        $db = Db::getInstance(); <============= HERE 

    return $db->escape($string, $htmlOK);
}
```

Why ?? Isn't the include of config.inc.php is suppose to make it works ?

I just want (from now) to be able to do something like :

```
$images_types = ImageType::getImagesTypes('products'); 
var_dump($images_types);
```

Answer (score 0):

we have a blog smart blog where use include the config.php like bellow code

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../init.php');
```

https://github.com/smartdatasoft/smartblog